# NestJS - Get current user from request and validate query params

Tags: nestjs

I have a route `/users` to get user list, the controller method needs to get current user, also needs to validate input query params. So I write like this:

```js
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), RolesGuard)
    @Roles(UserRole.GLOBAL, UserRole.ORG)
    @Get('users')
    findAll(@Request() req, @Query() query: FindAllUsersDto) {
      //code here.
    }
```

This works. I am wondering if this is a little duplication. Because I can use `req.query` to get query object. But if I don't write `@Query() query: FindAllUsersDto`, the validation pipe won't work. So is my code meaningful or is there a more simple way? Thanks.

Comment: How do you plan on getting the current user? What are you considering duplication here?

Comment: Since you are using JWT you can do `findAll(@Jwt() jwt: JWT, @Query() query: FindAllUsersDto)`. With this you will get current user from your jwt token.